# NCurses application not working in Docker [C#; .NET]

Tags: c#, .net, docker, ncurses

For learning purposes I'm trying to implement a simple application in C# using the [dotnet-curses](https://github.com/MV10/dotnet-curses) library. Application should simply catch user input from keyboard and then print it on terminal screen. I've implemented following code in Visual Studio and tested it to work on my host (Windows 10):

```
using System;
using Mindmagma.Curses;

namespace example
{
    class Program
    {
        private static IntPtr Screen;

        private static readonly Random rng = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Screen = NCurses.InitScreen();
            try
            {
                Echoer();
            }
            finally
            {
                NCurses.EndWin();
            }
        }

        static void Echoer()
        {
            NCurses.NoDelay(Screen, true); // get characters without waiting for ENTER
            NCurses.NoEcho(); // disable echoing characters to terminal

            NCurses.Keypad(Screen, true);

            bool exit = false;
            while (!exit)
            {
                int input_char = NCurses.GetChar();
                switch (input_char)  // GetCHar is blocking statement - it will wait for user to press any key
                {
                    case CursesKey.ESC:  // check if ESCAPED
                        NCurses.MoveAddString(2, 0, "EXCAPE pressed, closing");
                        exit = true;
                        NCurses.Refresh(); // refresh the terminal
                        break;

                    case -1: 
                        break;
                    
                    default: // if any other KEY pressed then print to screen
                        NCurses.MoveAddString(0, 0, $"Presses key was: {Convert.ToChar(input_char)}");
                        NCurses.Refresh(); // refresh the terminal
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to execute the application on Docker container it does not do anything. It doesnt give any error or anything, docker container just runs and then returns. Docker image was created with following docker file:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
# base image
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster
COPY ConsoleClient.exe /bin/
# dependencies
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
RUN apt -y install wget
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb 
RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
RUN apt update 
RUN apt -y install apt-transport-https
RUN apt -y install dotnet-runtime-3.1 
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "/bin/ConsoleClient.exe" ]
```

The dotnet-curses library should be cross-platform as I understood so it should run on both windows and linux. Am I maybe missing some .dll files? Do I need to somehow install that dotnet-curses library on my linux machine as well (my understanding is no, because its only needed for development and executable later should include all the necessary code)?

The dotnet-curses library uses *ncurses* underneath so thats why I installed that with apt in dockerfile.

**EDIT**
I know that the chosen base images might not be best for this and that there is some other code in Dockerfile that is not really required (e.g. EXPOSE port), but thats all for future purposes. I'm first trying to get this thing working.

Comment: curses applications have to run in a terminal.  The MinGW port will run only in a console window.  Your docker may not address that requirement.

Comment: But I can run  the container in interactive mode just fine so there should be a console available.

Comment: That's not necessarily the case if you're running it via another program.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I was trying to run a windows executable in linux. I guess thats the reason it didn't work. All-though I would have expected to get some kind of error.

Anyways, when I copied the .dll files of the application into docker and ran it with following command it worked

```
CMD [ "dotnet", "ConsoleClient.dll" ]
```